# Link para telefone react native

Tags: app, react, react-native, app-hibrido

Alguém saberia como colocar um link para abrir a chamada telefonica do smartphone quando o usuario clicar sobre o numero do telefone no apk ?

no aguardo ...

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se é seu caso, mas fazendo dessa forma com **`href="tel:999999999"`** vc consegue com que o Browser do *smartphone* reconheça o número como um número de telefone. Veja os exemplos

```
<span itemprop="telephone">
    <a href="tel:25266896">+55 (31) 2526-6896</a>
</span>

<span itemprop="telephone">
    <a href="tel:999816008">+55 (31) 99981-6008 (VIVO)</a>
</span>
```

***OBS:*** Algumas versões mais antigas do Safari convertem os número automaticamente em Link, podendo perder a sua formatação de CSS, então sugiro usar `<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">` para evitar problemas de estilo nos Safaris antigos.

Exemplo de como customizar o CSS para links de telefone:

```
a[href^="tel:"] {
    color: orange;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar um link de ancora html normal, especificando como sendo de telefone, assim como em um link de email:

ex:
`<a href="tel:00-000-000000" > 00-000-000000 </a>`